# How is it possible to use the type of a template parameter's member?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++14

My function looks like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
T myfunc(T a, T b) {
    // the type of a.data and b.data is U
    // ...
}
```

An example of type `T` and `U` looks like this:

```
class ExampleT {
public:
    int data;
};
```

Where `T` is the class, which has a member named `data`. And the type of `data` is `U`

My function has to be called at the moment with two type parameters:

```
myfunc<T, U>(...);
```

But the second type parameter (U) is the type of the `data` variable inside the first type (T). Is it possible, to remove the `U` from the template, and detect it for example using `decltype`?

All of the latest C++14 features may be used.

Comment: What's the point if I may ask? Why not a local typedef if you need one?

Comment: what do you want to do with the member? The answer can be as simply as `auto x = a.data;`

Comment: I would like to cast a variable to it's type, before assigning it to `data`

Comment: You can just static_cast<decltype(a.data)>(blahblahblah). There is no need to make it a template parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could deduce it as a default template parameter:

```
template<typename T, typename U = decltype(T::data)>
T myfunc(T a, T b) {
    // the type of a.data and b.data is U
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aef3c90a70387b26); Or within the function body:

```
template<typename T>
T myfunc(T a, T b) {
    using U = decltype(T::data);
    // ...
}
```

---

Or using a local typedef, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469575/how-is-it-possible-to-use-the-type-of-a-template-parameters-member/42469602#comment72079886_42469575) by Columbo

```
struct ExampleT {
    using Type = int;
    Type data;
};

template<typename T, typename U = typename T::Type>
T myfunc(T a, T b) {
    // ...
}
```